# How to call C# method in .cs file from Javascript function in .js file

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I've updated the question per the answers below. I think my main confusion is in the 'data' parameter and what to do with it in the js call.

C# method

```
[HttpPost]
        public string GetPreviewURL(string activityID)
        {
            try
            {
                var requestContext = ContextHandler.GetRequestContext(Request);

                object[] arguments = new object[] { requestContext };
                var sew= SumtContainer.Resolve<ICLWOrker>(typeof(ICLWOrker).FullName, arguments);

                return sew.GetPreviewUrl(activityID);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
        }
```

In this JS call the parameter after "POST" I think should be data, but I'm confused how to get the URL out of that from the JSON.

```
apiAccessClient = new apiClient();
        var apiUrl = STRING_SITE_PREFIX + '/service/webapi/GetPreviewURL/?activityID=' + actId;
        //define 'data' here?
        apiAccessClient.send(STRING_USERMODE, apiUrl, "POST", data, onPreviewSuccess, onError, 0, null, false, false, true); 
        return;
```

apiAccessClient is currently setup in a different js file which is where the Ajax call is setup

```
$.ajax({
    type: this.requestType,
    url: this.apiUrl,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    context: this,
    async: isAsync,
    data: JSON.stringify(flattenModel(this.parameters)),
    statusCode: {
        401: function () { _UTL_NavigateToTimeOutPage(); }
    },
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("X--AjaxRequest", "1");
        request.setRequestHeader("_SUMTC", _UTL_GetCSRFToken());
        request.setRequestHeader("EmulatorUserName", _UTL_GetEmulatorUserName());
        request.setRequestHeader("x--authenticationmode", "jwt");
        request.setRequestHeader("sumtotaljwt", _UTL_GetJWT());
        request.setRequestHeader("broker_Session_Id", _UTL_GetBrokerSessionId());
        if (userMode !== null && userMode.length > 0) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-UserMode", userMode);
        }
        request.setRequestHeader("x-viewableuserid", viewableUserId);
        if (!(isUndefinedOrNull(STRING_PROXYFORID))) {
            request.setRequestHeader("x-proxyforuserid", STRING_PROXYFORID);
            request.setRequestHeader("x-usermode", userMode);
        }

    },
    success: function (data, statusCode, jqXHR) {
        var contentType = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
        if ((jqXHR.status == 200) && contentType.toLowerCase().indexOf("text/html") < 0) {
            successCallback(data, this.currentContext);
        } else if ((dataReturnTypeText == true) && (jqXHR.status == 200)){
            successCallback(data, this.currentContext);             
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.status != 401) {
            if (errorCallback === null || errorCallback === undefined) {
                this.error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
            else {
                errorCallback(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How would I get it so the url I'm getting back is opened in a new window?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you have to make an ajx request

Comment: How is the file referenced where the method resides in the ajax call? Do I just put the project path?

Comment: To elaborate on @danielawhite said. Your client is running in a browser and your C# code is running on a server. You need to expose an endpoint on your server (perhaps using WebAPI) and then your Javascript code make a call back to the server and invole thae code at that endpoint

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments - JS runs on the client side (i.e in the browser) and C# runs on the server. To call your method you'll need to use AJAX. The client side code should look like this:

```
function launchURL_Test() {
var ID="your id";


 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourcontroller/GetUrl",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: "{'id':'" + ID + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

      // do something with the result...

    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log('error')

    }
});
}
```

NOTE: If you are not using controller, but code-behind instead, your methot should look like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetUrl(string id)
{
   //some code
   return url;
}
```

Or in standard MVC Controller your method should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetUrl(string id)
{
    //your code
    return url;
}
```

and finally, to open new window with URL from the method update your ajax success:

```
success: function (data) {

  window.open(data);

},
```

Comment: The front end page is a cshtml - leading me to think that Web Forms isn't in use, so no need to mention WebMethod. I wouldn't even mention it if Web Forms was in use.

Comment: This type of issue is new to me so pardon if these questions seem basic. If WebForms is not an option what is the easiest alternative? This particular codebase is a mixture of MVC, Angular, C#, etc... how would I know for sure?

Comment: I do have a REST controller to work with looks like.

Comment: Regular MVC controller will do just fine. Look at updated code

Comment: so, now you want it in a new window? I'm assuming that in the current window it is working fine now

Comment: Updated code above. I think the issue lies in my confusion on how to handle the data parameter